How to upload latest file from SFTP in azure synapse using ADF
I have 2 set of pairs of xlsx and pdf files in SFTP that need to upload in azure synape using ADF. I need to upload first the latest pair of file dumped in SFTP folder then after that just rerun the pipeline to get the next pair latest file.
Employee_81.xslx  01/02/2022 8:30:00 am
Employee_83.xslx  01/02/2022 8:40:00 am
Here, Employee_83 will be the first to upload.
This is what I tried:
ADF Activities:
Get Metada1:
Argument = Last Modified
FilterCondi:
@activity('Get Metada1').output.lastModified

@and(equals(item().type,'File'), and(endswith(item().name,'.xlsx'), startsWith(item().name,'Employee_')))

Run is successful but no file was uploaded in edl synapse. What went wrong?
EDIT:


Could you please provide your pipeline image? And where you want to upload the file in synapse?

pls see the EDIT section of my post. tnx.

can you check the below answer, does it helpful? let me know.

To achieve your requirement, you can follow below procedure:
Create two parameters date with least date value according to your requirement and fileName as shown below:

Use Get metadata activity to list the files in SFTP folder with Child items field list as shown below:

It will retrieve the files in folder, add foreach activity with sequential order and @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems items as shown below:

Create dataset with fileName string parameter for file name. Inside for each activity add Get meta data activity, use created dataset with Last modified field list,  @item().name value for fileName string parameter as shown below:

It will retrieve the last modified date for each file in the folder.  Add if condition activity to meta data activity with condition @greater(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified, variables('date'))

Inside if condition, for True condition add two set variable activities to update last modified date and last modified date file name as shown below:
latestModifiedDate(Set variable1):
date : @activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified


FileName(Set variable2):
fileName:@item().name


Add set variable activity after the foreach activity to get the last modified file name:
latestfileName:@variables('fileName')

It will give the latest modified file name as shown below:

Here is the pipeline json reference for your reference:
{
    "name": "pipeline4",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get Metadata2",
                            "type": "GetMetadata",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "dataset": {
                                    "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "fileName": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                "fieldList": [
                                    "lastModified"
                                ],
                                "storeSettings": {
                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                },
                                "formatSettings": {
                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get Metadata2",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@greater(activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified, variables('date'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "latestModifiedDate",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "date",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@activity('Get Metadata2').output.lastModified",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "FileName",
                                        "type": "SetVariable",
                                        "dependsOn": [
                                            {
                                                "activity": "latestModifiedDate",
                                                "dependencyConditions": [
                                                    "Succeeded"
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "variableName": "fileName",
                                            "value": {
                                                "value": "@item().name",
                                                "type": "Expression"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "latestFileName",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "ForEach1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "latestfileName",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@variables('fileName')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "date": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "2023-10-15T00:00:00Z"
            },
            "fileName": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "latestfileName": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}


@kimchigirl can you check the answer, does it helpful? let me know it
